# Issue getting SBT to work on Mac OS X

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use Miles Sabin's HList of his Shapeless project. So I installed sbt from Macports (this is version 0.11).

Unfortunately, when launching sbt, I have the following error message:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:24)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
```

Search google seems to point that sbt-launch.jar would be in classpath. But even though I export CLASSPATH to "", I still have the issue.

I also directly downloaded the sbt-launch.jar from typesafe, and running with java -jar, with exactly the same problem.

Any idea? Other people having the same issue?

EDIT

I've tracked the problem down to a Java extension under ~/Library/Java/Extensions/scala-library.jar

I have removed it and the problem is gone. I think this has been installed by the TypeSafe stack (TBC).

Comment: Not solving your general problem, but: There is a runner script in the shapeless repo. Have you tried to run it as `./sbt`?

Comment: Nope, haven't seen that using SBT on the Mac before.  Is it possible you have an old or nonstandard Java for some reason?  What do "which java" and "java -version" report?

Comment: OSX5114:~ leo$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)

Comment: I've tried ./sbt first, but it raised the exact same issue. I've reported. I also directly have the problem when launching sbt-launch.jar. Very strange. I could finely use Shapeless, on a previous version, before it included its compiler plugin depending on sbt, so I could recompile within Eclipse.

Comment: I was getting `IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method scala.Array$.unapplySeq` before I removed some jar-s from /Library/Java/Extensions/ (scala-library.jar among them). I myself placed it there.

Comment: Your edited part solved my problem, so upvoting your question:)

Comment: I just got this with 1.7.0_72. I don't have anything in my Java Extensions directory, and "sbt" command works just fine. I'm trying to run my play framework (2.3.6) app from IntelliJ under sbt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error, and generally uninstalling Java, and installing it again will resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

OP posted:

> I've tracked the problem down to a Java extension under `~/Library/Java/Extensions/scala-library.jar`
>
> I have removed it and the problem is gone. I think this has been installed by the TypeSafe stack (TBC).